# covering a baseboard heater gap and fire hazard

Tags: heater, fire-hazard

I noticed a mouse crawl up behind a baseboard heater. I unmounted the heater and found large holes in the wall. exposing styrofoam insulation.

is it a fire hazard to cover the holes with 1/4 inch galvanized mesh.  the heater will touch the mesh and the mesh is close to the styrofoam.

I have also considered filling the gap with greatstuff fireblock foam, however I have the same concern with the heater being close to or touching the fireblock foam.

Would speckle with mesh beca good option?

Any advice is appreciated.[image][image][image]

Comment: What type of baseboard heater?

Comment: I am not sure of the brand.   Here are photos

Answer (score 1):

I would not mount an electric baseboard heater on wire mesh.  Baseboard heaters have UL listings for installation and I doubt wire mesh is acceptable.

That wire mesh could heat up and catch the drywall paper on fire (or any paper that falls behind the unit.) The heating element is held out (away from) from the metal baseboard heater enclosure for a reason.

I’d seal the openings with plaster. It doesn’t have to be pretty, it’s going to be covered.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  If i seal the area with plaster would some mesh on the other side of the plaster be an issue?  I can try just plaster to start.   Also for the area with the 220v cable, can I encase the wire in plaster?

Comment: @Drew I wouldn’t use metal mesh anywhere near the heater, even when it’s covered with plaster. One small error and it could turn into a disaster. I’m not sure about 22v cable being encased in plaster...seems like it would be ok...

Comment: Thank you Lee Sam.  You have been  very helpful.  A few things. Is grreatstuff fireblock foam safe behind the plaster.   Also is it safe to have plaster touching. the power wire.  And what about fireblock foam touching the power wire

Comment: I don’t know, but that would be a good question for this site.

Answer (score 0):

These heaters are constructed so that the exterior surfaces (including the rear) do not reach dangerous levels (when instructions for maintaining air circulation are adhered to) . They will not even cause burns when touched, although they can get uncomfortably hot. There are few, if any, restrictions stated by manufacturers as to what the heaters may be installed in contact with. I see things like meltable plastics and low-density fiberboards (e.g. "beaverboard") mentioned in that regard. These heaters are routinely installed on wood and carpeting, and of course paper-faced wallboard. Providing a layer of metal mesh on the back will necessarily prevent actual contact with the backing surface, so should be all the less of a concern.